# What would this SQL query return?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

```
SELECT * FROM admin_user
WHERE first_name LIKE "m%d"
```

Comment: It would generate an error in SQL Server and most databases.

Comment: but what does it means?

Comment: Why don't you run the query and see what it returns? I don't understand why you ask this question. Isn't it faster to just run it and see?

Comment: because its from a test and I don't have where to run it

Comment: Double quotes are for delimited identifiers. I.e. `"m%d"` would be a column here, having the odd name `m%d`.

Comment: Tip: https://dbfiddle.uk/

Comment: @jarlh except in the tart that is MySQL (ANSI_QUOTES off)

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server

Answer (score 2):

the right syntax is :

```
SELECT * FROM admin_user
WHERE first_name LIKE 'm%d'
```

and it returns all the records that have firstname that start with character `m` and ands with character `d`.